# Downsample pointclouds from USGS (.LAZ) files in Python

Tags: geopandas, lidar, usgs, laspy

I am trying to process pointclouds from USGS for a project and I am having a hard time working with the data (.LAZ files) because they are very large. They have around 36 million points. I tried downsampling using open3d ([Voxel Down Sample](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.6.0/python_api/open3d.geometry.voxel_down_sample.html#open3d.geometry.voxel_down_sample)) But this caused a lot of loss in features in the LiDAR data.

Attaching a sample from the result from open3d: [image]

Is there a better alternative for this? Especially for geographical data.

Comment: You could crop the LAZ with a shapefile of your Area Of Interest.

Comment: Hey @Pointdump. Thanks for the help!  Yes, I am actually about to do that. But to do that I have to load this cloud into something like geopandas and clip it. But the script is crashing on me because the cloud is too big. That is why I am looking at downsampling options now

Comment: I haven't used GeoPandas, but cropping a point cloud with a shapefile is fairly straightforward with CloudCompare or LasTools. And CloudCompare can reduce a point cloud to any distance spacing between points.

Comment: Don't use geopandas, use software designed to work efficiently with lidar point clouds. E.g. [PDAL](https://pdal.io/) (if you can use command-line or python).  If the .laz is classified, start by filtering out points you're not interested in (or just keeping the classes of interest, i.e. the USGS lidar I downloaded over Yosemite is classified into ground, and vegetation heights plus lots of other classes that may not be useful). You can then resample using one of the many filters available.

Comment: E.g. `pdal translate --filters.expression.expression="(Classification >= 2 && Classification <= 5)" --filters.voxelcentroidnearestneighbor.cell=1 input.laz output.laz expression voxelcentroidnearestneighbor`

Comment: Thanks @Pointdump I do use Cloud Compare, but I am trying to work this into a python script so that it is automated and repeatable. Might have to look into how cloudcompare works like that. I havn;t used it much

Comment: Thank you @user2856 this is definitely helpful. The cloud I have is from Massachusetts, it is classified. Can I work pdal into a script too instead of CLI ? (Sorry I am new to all this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reccommend you use software designed to work efficiently with lidar point clouds rather than geopandas. For example [PDAL](https://pdal.io/) which can be [installed](https://pdal.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) in [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) easily:

```
conda create --yes --name myenv --channel conda-forge pdal python-pdal
```

If the .laz is classified, start by filtering out points you're not interested in (or just keeping the classes of interest, i.e. the USGS lidar I downloaded over Yosemite is classified into ground, and vegetation heights plus lots of other classes that may not be useful). You can then resample using one of the many [filters](https://pdal.io/en/latest/stages/filters.html) available.

Here's a python example that uses the [expression filter](https://pdal.io/en/latest/stages/filters.expression.html#filters-expression) to select ground and low-high vegetation [classification codes](https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/LAS_Specification.pdf) and then a [VoxelCentroidNearestNeighbor Filter](https://pdal.io/en/latest/stages/filters.voxelcentroidnearestneighbor.html#filters-voxelcentroidnearestneighbor) to downsample (there are other resampling filters available).  More python-pdal examples at https://pypi.org/project/pdal

```py
import pdal

## Example using a pipeline with a json string
pipeline = """[
    "input.laz",
    {
        "type": "filters.expression",
        "expression": "(Classification >= 2 && Classification <= 5)"
    },
    {
        "type": "filters.voxelcentroidnearestneighbor",
        "cell": "1"
    },
    "output.laz"
]"""

result = pdal.Pipeline(pipeline).execute()
print(result)  # result is the output point count


## Example using a pipeline with a pipeline objects
pipeline = (
        pdal.Reader("input.laz") |
        pdal.Filter.expression(expression="(Classification >= 2 && Classification <= 5)") |
        pdal.Filter.voxelcentroidnearestneighbor(cell=1) |
        pdal.Writer("output.laz")
)

result = pipeline.execute()
print(result)
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you for the help !